# html textbox funtion onkey_Up is not working on ascx control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ascx

i tried onkey_up to copy one textbos data to another textbox on an user control ascx file but when i run its not wroking.is it because of i wrote onkey_up function on .ascx , i should write on master page?

```
function sync() {
        var TextBoxA1 = document.getElementById('TestAmountTextBox');
        var TextBoxA2 = document.getElementById('TestAmountTextBox_2');
        TextBoxA2.value = TextBoxA1.value;
    }
```

---

html inpoutbox :

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="TestAmountTextBox" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="From " aria-label="From Transaction Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="7" onkeyup="sync()"/>                                                         
<input type="text" runat="server" id="TestAmountTextBox_2" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="To " aria-label="To Transaction Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="13" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, adding a textbox to a usercontrol will force ASP.NET to render a unique ID. Something like "usercontrolId_textboxId". You can find the actual ID, by viewing HTML source.

There are a few options to get around ASP.NET generated IDs:

**Option 1:**

You can turn off ASP.NET autogenerated IDs, by setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` E.g:

```
<input type="text"
      runat="server" 
      id="TestAmountTextBox" 
      ClientIDMode="Static"
      ... [the rest of the attributes]
```

There are alternative properties in ClientIDMode that can be used. Also it can be turned off completely in web.config.

If ClientIDMode is set to `Static`, then ASP.NET will throw an error if the same ID is reused. For example using the usercontrol on more than once on the same page.

**Option 2:**

Bind the ASP.NET ID to the JavaScript code, using `ClientID`, For example:

```
function sync() {
    var TextBoxA1 = document.getElementById('<%= TestAmountTextBox.ClientID %>');
    var TextBoxA2 = document.getElementById('<%= TestAmountTextBox_2.ClientID %>');
    TextBoxA2.value = TextBoxA1.value;
}
```

This will only work if the JavaScript is placed on the usercontrol.

**Option 3:**

A third option is to replace `getElementById` with `getElementsByClassName` and add another class to the textboxes.

Comment: I tried 2nd  option is flawlessly working ,Thanks a lot